# Bending pieces of an object

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm trying to bend an object but I'm encountering some problems. I've used the bend modifier to bend the base but now i have to bend the "arms" and its totally screwing up when i want to add another bend modifier. Any of you know how to do this correctly?

[image: text]

The object to the left is the one i would like to replicate. The one on the right is my sad object.

Link to source and amazing artist :
https://onemoreneon.com/

Thanks in advance

Comment: I converted your link into an embedded image, please next time use the editor's image tool. Try to better describe what is not as you expected, be more specific, it will help.

Comment: Why use a modifier and not model it bent from the start?

Comment: Well as i said im pretty new to blender. I don't really know the best workflow .. I tried multiple ways to create it with the bevel tool aswell but i just don't know how to get that "rounded effect" on the arms circled in blue

Comment: I'd use a [solidify modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html). Then you only have to model one side, vs modeling both the outside and inside.

Comment: Assign the arm vertices to a vertex group, specify this group in the deform modifier, you probably want to add an empty and use that as the axis origin for the bend. I think you would be better modeling this shape and not using modifiers to bend the main shape, modeling a thin shape and using solidify to add thickness would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this part of your object, you'd rather:

- Begin with a cubic shape.
- Add some vertical edge loops.
- Round the faces with the *Proportional Editing* option (*Sphere Falloff* mode).
- Give it a *Solidify* modifier.
- Round the angle edges with bevels (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>).
- Smooth your object with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Sharpen the edges with additional edge loops.
- When you're happy with the thickness, apply the *Solidify*.

[image]